# ORDER BY with bool > date > null in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a loooooooooooong SELECT ending with a ORDER BY that can include the following values :

- checked (1 or 0)
- date (YYYY-MM-DD)
- time (HH:MM:SS)

I'd like to order the result of the query the following way :

```
|__checked = 0
|            |__ date ASC
|            |__ time ASC
|            |__ date && time are null  
|__checked = 1
             |__ date ASC
             |__ time ASC
             |__ date && time are null
```

For now, I got something simple like "ORDER BY i1.checked, date, time" but the trouble is with this the items with empty date and times stay on the top.

---

Here is the whole query if you ever think you need all the data to find a proper solution. Don't scream.

```
SELECT i1._id AS _id, i1.title AS title, i1.checked AS checked, 

   // count the children (-1 is because the closure table include a relation between any item and itself)   
   (count( c1.item_id )  - 1) AS children_count, 

   // count the unchecked children 
   (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT i2._id) ) 
   FROM item AS i2 JOIN closure AS c2 ON (i2._id = c2.item_id) 
   WHERE c2.ancestor_id = i1._id 
   AND i2.checked = 0  
   AND c2.item_id NOT IN (0, i1._id)) AS unchecked_children_count, 

   // get the closest deadlines among the children :
   // if there is a date but no time, time is set to 00:00:00
   // if there is a time but not date, date is set to today
   // if there is no date nor time, both are set to an empty string

   // date
   ifnull(nullif((SELECT ifnull(nullif(i3.date, ""), date()) AS subdate
                  FROM item AS i3 JOIN closure AS c3 ON (i3._id = c3.item_id) 
                  WHERE c3.ancestor_id = i1._id
                  AND (i3.date OR i3.time) 
                  ORDER By subdate, ifnull(nullif(i3.time, ""), "00:00:00") 
                  LIMIT 1), ""), "") AS date, 

   // time           
   ifnull(nullif((SELECT ifnull(nullif(i4.time, ""), "00:00:00") AS subtime
                  FROM item AS i4 JOIN closure AS c4 ON (i4._id = c4.item_id) 
                  WHERE c4.ancestor_id = i1._id 
                  AND (i4.date OR i4.time) 
                  ORDER By ifnull(nullif(i4.date, ""), date()), subtime 
                  LIMIT 1), ""), "") AS time 

FROM item AS i1 JOIN closure AS c1 ON ( i1._id = c1.ancestor_id ) 
WHERE i1.parent_id = 0
AND c1.item_id != 0 

GROUP BY c1.ancestor_id 

ORDER BY i1.checked, date, time
```

The items are organised in a tree with a parent_id and a closure table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER BY il.checked, 
         CASE WHEN date IS NULL AND time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
         date, time
```

Comment: this was my first idea, but will that work straight off given that time & date are calculated values or will he have to wrap the whole lot up in an inner query ?

Comment: Try it and see.  I always forget when I can use a column alias and when I need to repeat the expression. Either way, you _won't_ need an inner query, but you might have to repeat your date and time expressions.  If that's the case, you might find an inner query is easier, or that you can combine them as one expression.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the case / when instruction. Standard SQL is full of surprises, I am constantly amazed of what you can do in one query instead of using massive nested for loops and IF / ELSE :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extra `temp` column in a wrapped select around all your sql to allow you to add an artificial order.

```
SELECT
    EACH_COLUMN
    , ...
    , CASE WHEN DATECol IS NULL AND TimeCol is NULL THEN 0 
         WHEN TimeCol is NULL THEN 1
         WHEN DATECol IS NULL THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END As ORDERCOL...

FROM
(
     INNER MESS OF ALL THE STUFF IN YOUR QUERY
)

ORDER BY
    ORDERCol DESC --Preserves order of BothCols Populated, Null Dates Next, Null Times Next, Both Nulls Last
    , Checked
    , Date
    , Time
```